# USB not visible in boot menu to install (windows 10 alongside pre installed ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi, laptop, hp

**Problem**:
I have ubuntu 20.04 pre installed and wanted to install windows 10 in dual boot.
**But during startup couldn't find usb drive in boot menu.**
I have used unetbootin to bootable windows 10 iso file. [Boot options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJEIz.jpg) 
[Boot from efi file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lQ6c.jpg)

**Trial-and-error**:
My system by default set to uefi and legacy mode is disabled.

Also, I have disabled secure boot in bios settings and in privacy settings only administrator and password available as some of articles suggested to select usb drive there.

*After searching all of tutorials mostly getting content on install ubuntu in windows system, hence, I'm totally out of options now.*

Pls help me!

Comment: Windows installation is off-topic here, try at superuser.com. Booting installation media media has nothing to do with the OS, if any. Furthermore Unetbootin AFAIK does not support the new Windows ISOs. Always prefer the official Media Creation Tool from a Windows machine. If one isn't available you may try WinWOE or MKUSB.

Comment: If you have no idea, how to correctly create a bootable usb try it with [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html). Ventoy also supports the latest Windows iso

Comment: Thanks, ventoy worked easily.  MKUSB was quite difficult